# Filling a column with formula using xlwings

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

I am trying to write code for coping values from on column to another column using excel formula with xlwings

[Sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTsAy.png)

If I am using above code it is coping the cell value of V3 to B3.

[expected code or result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXEWw.png)

But I want to copy values of each cells of V to B make iterrows like below

But it was not working.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text into actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting). Can you please read about [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) and apply what you learn to improve your question post? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to use an [f-string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) to format the text:

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
    xw.Range(f"B{i}").formula = f"=V{i}"
```

A much more efficient way to do the above is setting a range of cells to the formula of the first cell, as the rest will be relative without absolute referencing:

```
n = 10
sheet.range("B1:B"+str(n)).formula = "=V1"
```

So by using the above, cells B1:B10 will have have the values of the cells V1:V10.

I would also suggest using `sheet.range()` instead of `xw.Range()` as this will ensure the correct sheet is being edited.

Comment: Thank you Rawson, I tried code as per your recommendation and it is running without any error but values from the cells are not coping.

Comment: So when you look at the range of cells B1 to Bn there is no formula within that is `=V1` etc.?

Comment: Sorry my mistake not saved the variable so it was not copied. Thank you.

Comment: Can you help me one more similar doubt? I want to added date in the formula which taken from a input test_date=input("Enter the Date in DD/MM/YYYY:") then want to add into the middle of the formula sheet.range("H1:H"+str(n+1)).formula = '=DATEDIF(R2,'+date(test_date)+',"d")'. Date does not have change for each row

Comment: So `test_date = "01/01/2023"; test_date = dt.datetime.strptime(test_date, "%d/%m/%Y"); xw.Range("H1:H"+str(n+1)).formula = f'=DATE({test_date.year}, {test_date.month}, {test_date.day}) - R1'` would fill the cells with the formula calculating the difference between the date in column R with the input date.  Is this what you were trying to do?

Comment: Alternatively: `xw.Range("H1:H"+str(n+1)).formula = f'=DATEVALUE("{str(test_date)}") - R1'` will work, and looks neater.  This just converts the date as a string to an Excel recognised date.  I don't have a `=DATEDIF()` function in Excel, but this will work in the same way for days.

Comment: Thank you. Date form will be month/date/year. I tried with above method  sheet.range("H2:H"+str(n+1)).formula = '=DATEDIF(R2,'+ DATE({date_input.month}, {date_input.date}, {date_input.year})+',"d")' but still it is not working

Comment: To use the Excel `DATE` function, you need to enter values for Year, Month, Day in that order.  You should change the formula output to: `f'=DATEDIF(R2, DATE({date_input.year}, {date_input.month}, {date_input.day}), "d")'`.  If you are using an f-string, you don't need to end the string to add in the next section, it was not correct how you had written it.

Comment: Hi Rawson, Thank you for your support. Yes, the cells with the formula calculating the difference between the date in column R with the input date. Code f'=DATEVALUE("{str(Test_Date)}")-R2 I am getting results like "8/22/1900" but my expected result is like 43. other method giving me errors does not match format. I tried %Y%m%d, %m%d%Y and %d%m%Y

Comment: You just need to change the formatting of the cell and it will return the correct number.  Change it to General.